# Eclipse: XDoclet Plugin is setting wrong ejb-client-jar in ejb-jar.xml

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, ejb, xdoclet

I am working with an old Enterprise app which uses EJB 2.1. The app was build in 2000s using Eclipse and XDoclet 1.2.3.

The app consist of 1 Enterprise Application Project named `AppEar`, 1 EJB Project named `AppEjb`, 1 EJB Client Project named `AppEjbClient`, 1 Utility Project named `AppSrc` and 1 Dynamic Web Project named `AppWeb`.

The `ejb-jar.xml` is located in `ejbModule\META-INF` folder of `AppEjb` project and points to `AppEjbClient` project by having this entry :

```
<ejb-client-jar>AppEjbClient.jar</ejb-client-jar>
```

I upgrade the app to Eclipse Kepler (My workspace is `D:\WORK\WORKSPACE-eclipse-jee-kepler`). But the issue I am having is XDoclet Plugin is now setting wrong ejb-client-jar in ejb-jar.xml. This is how it is setting now:

```
<ejb-client-jar>AppSrc.jar</ejb-client-jar>
```

So somehow the XDcolet plugin is now thinking that `AppSrc` is the EJB Client Project instead of `AppEjbClient`.

I investigated a bit and find that the XDcolet plugin runs the ant script `tempAnt.xml` which is located in `.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.ejb.annotations.xdoclet` folder of the workspace. That folder also has a `build.properties` file which has 2 properties related to the EJB Client Module:

> ejb.dd.clientjar=AppSrc.jar 
>   ejb.client.module.src=D:/WORK/WORKSPACE-eclipse-jee-kepler/AppSrc/src

I thought I just need to change them in `build.properties` file to point to right EJB Client so I change them this way:

> ejb.dd.clientjar=AppEjbClient.jar 
>   ejb.client.module.src=D:/WORK/WORKSPACE-eclipse-jee-kepler/AppEjbClient/ejbModule

Save the `build.properties` file and then do clean and build the whole workspace again.

But still got the same wrong ejb-client-jar in ejb-jar.xml.

Check the `build.properties` file in `.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.ejb.annotations.xdoclet` folder and it was reverted back by removing my changes. So XDoclet Plugin overwrites this file.

How can I fix this so it pick the correct ejb-client-jar in ejb-jar.xml?

Answer (score 0):

We run in the same issue recently. The way to overcome this was to remove the Utility Project from the eclipse workspace, as dependecies were resolved via maven poms anyway.
After that, the client under `Java EE Tools > Remove EJB Client` (and thus in  *ejb.dd.clientjar*) was set correctly.
Probably some bug similar to this https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=122274.